# How to use i18n component interpolation in Nuxt 3?

Tags: internationalization, nuxtjs3, nuxt-i18n

I have a project that uses Nuxt 3 with the following dependencies:

```json
"@nuxtjs/i18n": "8.0.0-beta.4",
"nuxt": "3.0.0",
```

The problem is that I can't use the `<i18n>` tag like I did before with Nuxt 2 version.

For example:

```html
<i18n
  tag="h1"
  path="homepage.welcome.title"
  class="title"
>
  <template v-slot:frameworkType>
  <span class="text-nuxt-lightgreen">
    Vue
      </span>
  </template>
</i18n>
```

How can I use this code with Nuxt 3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works differently now, since you need to use `vue-i18n` v9 with Nuxt 3.

The syntax is similar but slightly different:

```html
<i18n-t
  tag="h1"
  keypath="homepage.welcome.title"
  class="title"
>
  <template #frameworkType>
    <span class="text-nuxt-lightgreen">
      Vue
    </span>
  </template>
</i18n-t>
```

Note the following changes:

- Replace `<i18n>` tag with `<i18n-t>`
- Replace `path` attribute with `keypath`

See the official docs https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/component.html for more details.

Comment: Where can I see the documentation for this?

Comment: I found this: https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/component#slots-syntax-usage